# How to create a session in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

Total Cassandra newbie here, using Python client.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])
session = cluster.connect()
```

I get error:

> Exception in thread event_loop (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in `__bootstrap_inner`
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 504, in run
>   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cassandra_driver-1.0.2-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/cassandra/io/asyncorereactor.py", line 52, in _run_loop
>   : `__exit__`

I want to create my first table and can't get past session.

```
query = "create table timeseries (
  event_type text,
  insertion_time timestamp,
  event blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (event_type, insertion_time)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (insertion_time DESC);"

session.execute(query)
```

Comment: What version of the driver are you using?

Comment: 2.0.6 on ubuntu 12.04

Comment: pip install cassandra-driver = 1.0.2

Comment: If you run the same code from the python interactive interpreter do you have the same issue?

Comment: Are you running your code on the same server as Cassandra?  Also, in your `cassandra.yaml` what is your `listen_address` set to?